# How to get the slope of the last trend segment in prophet library

Tags: r, time-series, facebook-prophet, trendline

I'm using facebook prophet library to detect trend changes in stock price.

[changepoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXpAG.png)

I need the last trend segment's slope to detect trend direction (if it goes up or down). I have looked into the model object but did not find needed data.